# Unable to connect to snowflake database in airflow using SnowflakeOperator with private key

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to snowflake database in airflow by using SnowflakeOperator which operates on created snowflake connection in airflow UI portal (see linked picture below)

[top part of my snowflake connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umd35.png)

where all essential fields are populated including Host, Login, Warehouse, Account, Database, Role and Private key (Text). However, when triggering the DAG I am facing the following error:

**TypeError: Password was given but private key is not encrypted.**

I have not been able to find the answer to resolve this, so it might be a simple issue which I am missing (I am very new to software engineering coding), such as using some tools to encrypt the key. Any help or tips here would be appreciated!

Comment: Snowflake supports [key pair authentication](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html) with both encrypted/unencrypted version of private key. Do you use a private key with password or without? The error message suggests your private key has no password.

Comment: My private key was generated without encryption (with openssl and -nocrypt), and since snowflake should support both encrypted and unencrypted keys I thought this should work. Or are you suggesting that I should use a private key with password, hence an encrypted private key here to connect to snowflake in airflow?

Comment: It is not mandatory to have a private key with encryption. Did you set anything on PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE in the connection definition for Snowflake? The error suggests you've set this parameter but you're using a private key without encryption (-nocrypt like you mentioned).